# NodeJS API on AWS Elastic Beanstalk showing 502 Bad Gateway Error when connecting to external SQL Database

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-security-group

Okay, here's the situation. I've managed to build and deploy a NodeJS API using AWS Elastic Beanstalk. It's working properly and is currently up and running. However, when I navigate to the endpoint route, it takes too long and ultimately shows a 502 Bad Gateway error, despite functioning and providing a response perfectly fine on my local machine.

Please note that my NodeJS app connects to an SQL database that is not part of any AWS service.

I've already created a security group for my EC2 instance associated with my Beanstalk app and modified the inbound/outbound rules of the firewall. I've opened the inbound/outbound traffic for HTTP, HTTPS, MSSQL, and even all traffic, along with SSH and RDP. Despite saving these changes, it's still not working.

Does anyone have any idea why this connection error is occurring?

Comment: Have you checked Elastic Beanstalk logs? What is the error you see in the logs?